# Android ACRA form key?

Tags: android

I just started to build the concept using ACRA which will capture crashing error. And I want it to be emailed.

I am follwing this ....
http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Sending_reports_for_caught_exceptions_or_for_unexpected_applicat

So what is a form key? And where should I get it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACRA can deliver the crash report using several different methods. one of those methods is posting to a google docs form. the form key is the google docs form key.

with the email method, the form key is not relevant. it's only for use with the google docs form method.

as a side note, the google docs method is the easiest and simplest to use. unless there's a reason why you need delivery via email, use google docs. you can even configure the form so you get an email when the form is updated - best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the ACRA wiki [BasicSetup](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/BasicSetup#Setting-up_your_project).

In short, you have to copy the `CrashReports-template.csv` file from ACRA to Google Docs and create a form from it. Google Docs will then create a formKey for the form, which you can find in the link at the bottom of the form creation page.

**EDIT:**
Jeffrey Blattman's answer is more relevant, the formKey is not required in case of emailing the crash report.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It took me forever to know where form key is coming from.